# Laravel: DATE_ADD in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to subtract days from the db column and then compare it with the current date using `DATE_ADD` function. Is this possible?

```
 $valid_status_query->whereRaw('DATE_ADD("d",-3, "date_to")', '<=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
```

For example, if the column date is `2022-07-20` then it should use `2022-07-17` to compare in `where` clause at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
$valid_status_query->whereRaw("DATE_SUB(date_to, INTERVAL 3 DAY) <= ?", [Carbon::now()->toDateString()]);
```

Comment: Why did you add `?` along with `<=` operator?

Comment: It is SQL binding, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-methods